# Convert Math object to real object

Tags: javascript

Is there a nice way to convert `Math` object into "real" javascript object?

I want to use `Object.keys` on `Math` object. Is that possible to not hardcode it all the way down?

Comment: The properties of the Math object are not enumerable. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I need to wrap every Math function in another function and I was wondering if I have to do this in the hard way.

Comment: Its not "dupe" since I wanted to convert `Math` object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The properties of `Math` are not enumerable, so `Object.keys(Math)` returns an empty array.

However, you can use

```js
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(Math)
```

It will produce something like

```js
["toSource","abs","acos","asin","atan","atan2","ceil","clz32","cos","exp","floor","imul","fround","log","max","min","pow","random","round","sin","sqrt","tan","log10","log2","log1p","expm1","cosh","sinh","tanh","acosh","asinh","atanh","hypot","trunc","sign","cbrt","E","LOG2E","LOG10E","LN2","LN10","PI","SQRT2","SQRT1_2"]
```

Comment: Well, that's what I wanted to achieve, thanks!